# Nested multiline comments in ruby?

Tags: ruby, nested, comments

I'm fairly new to ruby. I've noticed that multiline comments are not nestable. This code causes an error:

```
=begin
=begin
=end
=end
```

this is the error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '='
    from C:/Ruby/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way to nest comments in ruby?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by nested comment. Please define what it means.

Comment: You could indent the inner `=begin` / `=end` pair. It also helps readers to better understand the nested structure.

Comment: @sawa when you have another `=begin` / `=end` in a `=begin` / `=end` multi-line comment.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is.  The problem ruby sees here is like this:

```
=begin   # start comment
=begin   # still commenting
=end     # end commenting
=end     # wtf is this?
```